# Socket: bind address not supported by protocol

Tags: linux, sockets, gcc

Source code for a simple TCP echo server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER  1024
#define PORT       20000

int main()
{
  int lsock,csock, ret, in , i;
  int yes = 1;
  char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
  char* c;
  struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  struct sockaddr_in cliaddr; // connector's address information

  if((lsock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP))<0){
      perror("socket");
      exit(0);
  }

  bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  if(bind(lsock,(struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr))<0) {
            close(lsock);
            perror("server: bind");
            return -1;
  }

  if(listen(lsock,5)<0){
           perror("listen");
           exit(0);
  }else{     
           printf("Server listening on port %i\n",PORT);
  }

  while(1){
     int len = sizeof(cliaddr);
     bzero(&cliaddr,len);

     if(csock = accept(lsock,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&len)<0){
           perror("accept");
           exit(0);
     } 

     printf("New client connected....\n");

     in = recv(csock,(void*)&buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);

     if(in <0){
            perror("recvmsg");
            close(csock);
            exit(0);
     }else if(in==0){    
           printf("client disconnected\n");
           close(csock);
     }else{

       if(send(csock,(void*)buffer,sizeof(buffer),0)<0){
        perror("sendmsg");
            close(csock);
       }
     }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles just fine. But whenever I execute the output file I get the following error message:

```
server: bind: Address family not supported by protocol
```

I used netcat commands to test the network interfaces including listening and connecting to the loopback interface and so it does not appear to be a kernel issue. But **no matter what address I try to bind to it returns the same error message**. I even say a bug report for GCC which mentioned this specific error some 7 years ago so I am obviously not the 1st person to have this problem(that was with a previous version of GCC). I have GCC version 4.7.3. Does anyone have the 4.8.X versions with updated glibc libraries? If so I wonder if this bug persists.

Comment: Can you call `perror` before `close` ?

Comment: Yep. I just did that and it makes no difference.

Comment: Your code works fine for me with gcc 4.8.2 (glibc 2.18) and clang 3.4

Comment: I've only ever seen this when I mismatched the `AF_` option between the `socket` call and the `bind` server address `sin_family` member.

Comment: John, I think it might be time to upgrade to GCC 4.8.2 and get a newer version of glibc.

Comment: @Phat_Albert Did it ever work? Are you using a toolchain from a distribution? Did you change **anything**? what does strace of the program show? (the bind should look like: `bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(20000), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16)` )

Comment: FYI: I have `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3` but your code works fine for me: `$ ./socket_bind 
Server listening on port 20000`

Comment: Guys, I got the bind to work by directly implementing a system Cal l call function.

Answer (score 0):

So I modified the  header by adding the  header to it(which has the actual syscall numbers for the socket functions). And replaced the "bind" function which had previously implemented with a prototype(that links to the Glibc library)as:

```
extern int bind(int sockfd,  __SOCKADDR_ARG addr, socklen_t addrlen)__THROW;
```

With an actual implementation that makes a direct system call using the value for bind from the __NR_syscall table:

```
int bind(int sockfd,  __SOCKADDR_ARG addr, socklen_t addrlen)
{

     _syscall3(int,bind,int,sockfd,__SOCKADDR_ARG,addr,socklen_t,addrlen)


} __THROW;
```

The output after compiling and execution of the output file.

```
Server listening on port 20000
```

**w00t!w00t!**